# 404 error on the default page on my Gitlab repository

Tags: html, css, github, gitlab, hosting

This is my first time using Gitlab.
My repository url is `myusername.gitlab.io/myrepo`.
Opening that page gives me a 404 error, however when I open  `myusername.gitlab.io/myrepo/myindex.html`, I get my index page.

Can someone tell me how I can set it so `myusername.gitlab.io/myrepo` loads `myusername.gitlab.io/myrepo/myindex.html`.

On a second note, I have seen other projects that use username.gitlab.io`without the need for the`/therepo` suffix.
Can anyone tell me how I can remove the suffix and just use the domain to access my repo.

Comment: For your first question, please include the error message. For your second question please do your research about "gitlab custom domain"

Answer (score 1):

Your server may prefer a default 'index' file to be loaded. In some cases, it may not handle the default file at all.

Rename you index file from `myindex.html` to `index.html`

Comment: i will let  u know

Answer (score 0):

First, to start, you can fork a pre-set project, with the right files in it (including an index.html): see [`gitlab.com/pages`](https://gitlab.com/pages) for examples, and "[Getting started](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/#getting-started)" for the steps
.

> I really want to have myusername.github.io only

Second, that is a [user website](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html#user-and-group-websites): make sure your repo (where you have forked/cloned the project example) is named after your GitLab login: `<you>.gitlab.io`.